# Highcharts change look of tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

for my project I need to change the look of tooltip. 
I found in the api documentation, to set useHTML to true, but it doesn't help.

here is my example:

```
tooltip: {
          borderWidth: 0,
          style: {
              padding: 0
          },
          useHTML: true,

          formatter: function(){
              return '<div style="float:left"><small>' + this.series.name + 
                     '</small></div><br/><div style="float:left;">test:</div>' + 
                     '<div style="float:left;padding-left: 30px;"><b>' +
                     this.point.test + 
                     '</b></div>';
              }


          }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/147/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the tooltip out of the plotOptions http://jsfiddle.net/ahZWS/.

```
    var options = {

        ...

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            style: {
                padding: 0
            },
            useHTML: true,

            formatter: function(){
                return '<div style="float:left"><small>' + this.series.name + 
                    '</small></div><br/><div style="float:left;">test:</div>' + 
                    '<div style="float:left;padding-left: 30px;"><b>' + this.point.test + 
                    '</b></div>';
            }


        },
        plotOptions: {
            ...
        }
        , series: seriesArr
    };
```